# React with Redux: Call a function after updating the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to make sure that the store is already updated and I can invoke a function that needs the updated store?

Comment: Use lifecycle methods?

Comment: Use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 2):

Once you update the store. You can get updated global state within connected component in `componentWillReceiveProps`like this :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  //invoke function with updated store
  //this.foo(nextProps)
  console.log(this.props); // prevProps
  console.log(nextProps); // currentProps after updating the store
  }
```

And you can also use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used shouldComponentUpdate

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.someArray.length !== nextProps.someArray.length) {
    /* some function here */
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This isn’t for utilising update state. It’s actually recommended to use where you want to stop unmeasurable re rendering. But I believe we should structure our app like there are none unnecessary re renders. In React docs about shouldComponentUpdate(); “return false to tell React update can be skipped”..have a look on docs. Feel to ask any question.

Comment: @Sakhi Mansoor, so maybe componentDidUpdate(prevProps) will be a good place to call a method after the store update?

Comment: Check my answer above, you get updated store in props in both methods. Every life cycle has different semantics. Often we take these things for granted and they become a great pain when our app grows.

Comment: Ok @Sakhi Mansoor